# How to save JUST a value from a firestore document in Vuex instead of the whole object?

Tags: vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, vue-component, vuex

I have a Vue component that retrieves data from a firestore document, i tried to save just the value of the document in a vuex state, but instead of saving just the value of the document, it saves the whole object, i mean the fieldname and the value.

Here's my component's code:

```
created() {
    var docRef = db.doc("rates/ratesData");
    docRef
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          this.$store.commit("setRate", doc.data());
        } else {
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }
```

Store.js:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    currentRate: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setRate(state, value) {
      state.currentRate = value;
    }
  }
});
```

I want the state to look like this:
[I can't post images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9mEY.png)

But it looks like this: 
[I still can't post images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8aGH.png)

My english is bad, sorry.

Comment: Could you edit the question to be clear about what you would like it to do instead of what it does now?  `doc.data()` returns an object with all of the fields in the document.  Do you want something different?

Comment: Yes, instead of the whole object, i just want the value of the object... The object returns `rateStatus: 75662.78`
I just want it to return `75662.78`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `doc.data()`, just pass the property of the document object you want.  Try `doc.data().rateStatus`.